# to check the required property of a given graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Can a graph be self-centered if it contains a vertex of degree one. The simplest counter example that came to my mind is Path.
But how to prove the statement if we consider any graph with a vertex of degree one.
A self-centered graph is a graph whose diameter equals its radius. Or where the eccentricity of every vertex is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be a vertex of degree one, $b$ a vertex adjacent to $a$. Then ${\rm eccentricity}(a)={\rm eccentricity}(b)+1$ if the graph contains at least 3 vertices.

Comment: oh.... Thanks for the idea. I mean i may take graph G as self-centered with eccentricity 'd' of all vertex except the vertex 'a'. and then to find out the eccentricity of 'a' we use eccentricity(a)=eccentricity(b)+1 and thus ecc of 'a' is different from other vertices. Am i right sir??

Comment: I mean I may take G as a graph where ecc of every vertex is 'd' except vertex 'a'.

Comment: Yes, you are right.